# How change the 'status' value in firestore when user is active?

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to check if the user using the app or not.

If user uses the app or not, than change its value in my firestore.

Eg: If user is active, then the firestore field is like:

```
   'status' : active(or true)
```

If user is inactive or leave the app than firestore value will be like.

```
    'status' : inactive(or false)
```

Comment: Sounds like you have two different problems here.  One is determining if the user is "active", and the other is writing to Firestore.  Writing to Firestore should be trivial, so really want you want to think about is how to determine when the user transitions between active and inactive.  You will also need to think about what happens if the user is using your app from multiple devices.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this approach is going to be writing the `inactive` value. When do you expect to write that value? Because once the user exits the app, the client-side code can't write it anymore. So unless you have the user explicitly mark themselves as `inactive` while they still in the app, you'll need some server-side component to detect that the user is gone.

The Firebase Realtime Database has a feature to support this type of presence system, but Firestore does not due to the way its wire protocol works. You might want to look at this solution in the Firebase docs on how to use the Realtime Database to build a presence system on Firestore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence